# My Samsung S7 keeps getting popups saying that "Google Play Services has stopped" and restarting itself

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, factory-reset

My Samsung S7 keeps getting popups saying that Google Play Services or Knox Enrollment keeps stopping while I'm setting up my phone. It was constantly restarting beforehand, so I factory reset it, but it's doing the same thing it was a few days ago when I bought the phone and set it up the first time. Did I just get a bad phone?